# Extracting value from Dataframe column of type list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe column as below:

```
['linkdetail[completeDate=<null>, endDate=2019-01-12T00:30:00.000Z,
  goal=,id=101,name=proj_1, rapidViewId=5,sequence=200,
  startDate=2019-01-12T10:30:47.341Z,state=ACTIVE]']
['linkdetail[completeDate=<null>, endDate=2019-11-12T00:30:00.000Z,
  goal=,id=101,name=proj_2, rapidViewId=5,sequence=200,
  startDate=2019-01-12T10:30:47.341Z,state=CLOSED]']
```

I am trying to extract the below fields from the above column.

Expected output

```
name, state
proj_1, ACTIVE
proj_2, CLOSED
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex pattern having named capturing groups, you can test the regex pattern [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/2CQF1T/2):

```
d = df['col'].str.extract(r'name=(?P<name>[^,]*).*?state=(?P<state>[^,\]]*)')
```

Result:

```
print(d)

     name   state
0  proj_1  ACTIVE
1  proj_2  CLOSED
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using regex extract

**Ex:**

```
data = ['linkdetail[completeDate=<null>, endDate=2019-01-12T00:30:00.000Z,goal=,id=101,name=proj_1, rapidViewId=5,sequence=200,startDate=2019-01-12T10:30:47.341Z,state=ACTIVE]']
['linkdetail[completeDate=<null>, endDate=2019-11-12T00:30:00.000Z,goal=,id=101,name=proj_2, rapidViewId=5,sequence=200,startDate=2019-01-12T10:30:47.341Z,state=CLOSED]']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['test'])
df[['name', 'state']] = df['test'].str.extract(r"name=(.*?),.*state=(.*)\]", expand=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                                test    name   state
0  linkdetail[completeDate=<null>, endDate=2019-0...  proj_1  ACTIVE
```